# jQuery, Javascript: Responsive site - execute function below 480px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin that hides a menubar. But i only want this to happen below 480px document size (aka, on phones, not on desktop computers).

```
var wi;
$(window).ready(function() {
    wi = $(window).width(); 
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    wi = $(window).width();
});

$(function() {
    if(wi<480){
        $('nav').scrollUpMenu({
            waitTime: 200,
            transitionTime: 150,
            menuCss: { 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0'}
        });
    }
});
```

The scrollUpMenu() code is from https://github.com/dvdsmpsn/Scroll-Up-Menu

Now when I open the website it works. When I resize the window from desktop to phone size (<480px), it will not hide the menu when scrolling. But if I refresh the page at that size, it will. And vice versa. I thought my $(window).resize function would take care of it, but I guess not. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: ***As a side note:*** `$(window).ready(...);`, even calling `ready()` method on empty object would work in most case, you have to call it on `document`

Comment: To check for viewport width, you'd have better to use `window.matchMedia`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia  This handles better all type of devices

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to execute the width check in the resize event:

```
var wi;
$(window).ready(function() {
    wi = $(window).width();
    checkWidth();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    wi = $(window).width();
    checkWidth();
});

function checkWidth() {
    if(wi < 480){
        $('nav').scrollUpMenu({
            waitTime: 200,
            transitionTime: 150,
            menuCss: { 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0'}
        });
    }
}
```

A cleaner solution would be something like this:

```
$(window).on('load resize',
    function () {
        if($(window).width() < 480){
            $('nav').scrollUpMenu({
                waitTime: 200,
                transitionTime: 150,
                menuCss: { 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0'}
            });
        }
    }
);
```

This way you're binding the event listeners to `window` in 1 call.

Comment: I would suggest making `wi` a parameter of `checkWidth()` instead of a global variable (or just getting the width inside `checkWidth()`).

Comment: @JLRishe: I added a second option.

Comment: There is no `onready` event for window object, i guess you mean `onload` EDIT: ok i see this is coming from OP's code ;)

Comment: I used your 'cleaner solution'. And when I take the edge of the browser window and resize it to below 480px, it works. But when I resize it back up to 1000px it still hides the menu on scrolling.

Comment: You'll need to add a `else` that disables the `scrollUpMenu`, then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your handler on the resize event.

But it is best to keep a flag of the state so that you only run your code once per layout change

```
$(function(){
    var breakpoint = 480,
        state = 'big';

    function handleLayout(){
       var width = $(window).width();

       if (width < breakpoint && state === 'big') {
           state = 'small';
           $('nav').scrollUpMenu({
               waitTime: 200,
               transitionTime: 150,
               menuCss: { 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0'}
           });
       } else if (width >= breakpoint && state === 'small') {
           state = 'big';
           // do what you want to revert to normal here..
       }
    }

    $(window).resize(handleLayout).trigger('resize');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with A. Wolff's matchMedia, and for initial/resize check Cerbrus' function:

```
$(window).on('load resize',
    function () {
        var mq  = matchMedia('(max-width: 480px)');
        if (mq.matches) {
            document.title = 'mobile';
        }else{
            document.title = 'desktop';
        }
    }
);
```

Because it has the best device support and performance
http://jsperf.com/matchmedia-vs-resize/3

Comment: Keep in mind that `matchMedia` has [limited browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia), especially IE is late to support it.